# draggable inside Canvas element

Tags: canvas, drag-and-drop

I'm facing a problem with canvas. I implemented a solution to drag and drop images inside a Canvas element (a grid actually). Once the image is dropped, it can't be re-dragged, which limits the flexibility of the solution. Did I miss a line?

```
function dragDrop(e,ui){

    // get the drop point (be sure to adjust for border)
    var x=parseInt(ui.offset.left-offsetX)-1;
    var y=parseInt(ui.offset.top-offsetY);

    // get the drop payload (here the payload is the $tools index)
    var theIndex=ui.draggable.data("toolsIndex");

    // drawImage at the drop point using the dropped image 
    ctx.drawImage($tools[theIndex],x,y,32,32);

}
```

I referred to this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/cyur7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html canvas is a fixed bitmap, so images cannot natively be dragged.  (Images drawn on a canvas become a permanent part of the existing drawing).

To make images draggable on canvas, you have to redraw all of the canvas with the "dragged" image moved to your new desired location.

**Step#1:** *Keep track of every one of your image objects and where they need to be on the canvas*

Create an array filled with javascript objects that define the image and its location

```
var images=[];

images.push({
    x:100,
    y:100,
    width:yourImageElement.width,
    height:yourImageElement.height,
    image:yourImageElement
});
```

**Step#2:** *Listen for mouse events and create a dragging system based on those events*

On mousedown:

- iterate through each image in the images array.
- test each image to see if the mouse is over that image (see example of hit testing below).
- save a reference to the "hit" image in a variable: var selected=images[hitIndex]
- if the mouse is over an image, set an isDragging flag: var isDragging=true;

On mousemove:

- calculate the distance the mouse has moved since the last mousemove event
- add that distance to the x,y of the selected image
- redraw everything on the canvas
- since you changed the x,y of the "dragging" image it will appear to have moved!
- repeat with every mousemove

On mouseup:

- clear the isDragging flag because the drag is over and the image has been repositioned

Hit-testing Example: Is mouse over an image?

```
var thisImageIsUnderMouse=(
    mouseX>=image.x 
    && mouseX<=image.x+image.width
    && mouseY>=image.y
    && mouseY<=image.y+image.height
)
```